# Center Flexbox on Part of Element

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I am trying to use flexbox to vertically center two elements along the blue line shown in the picture below.

[image: Example 1]

The problem is that the second box and the text are part of one div and flexbox wants to align them like this:

[image: Example 2]

By making the div `position: relative` and the text `position: absolute` I am able to accomplish my goal, except that this causes the entire container to exclude the text in calculating the height of the container:

[image: Example 3]

How can I center these elements correctly while still allowing the container to have the height of all content in the container?

**Desired Result:**

[image: Desired Result]

**Example of Problem:** (While the boxes are centered, the container does not include the text, as shown by a blue border.)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 4px solid #00aaff;
}

.big-box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 4px solid black;
}

.small-box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 4px solid black;
}

.group {
  position: relative;
}

.group p {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="big-box">
    Lots of content...
  </div>

  <div class="group">
    <div class="small-box">
      Some content...
    </div>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: am I correct in understanding you basically want the right column (with short box and text beneath) to be vertically offset from the top of the blue box, while also causing the blue box to wrap all contained content?

Comment: Is there any content in the boxes?

Comment: @MitchTalmadge could you place your code into a snippet please?

Comment: @DacreDenny More than offset, I'd like the short box to be perfectly centered with the large box. It works great when the text does not exist, but adding the text causes the small box to shift upwards so that the small box + text are centered with the large box.

Comment: You may want to switch to grid layout?

Comment: @yunzen Yes there is. I'll make a snippet soon to clarify.

Comment: @yunzen I would be open to using grid layout

Comment: Is there any chance of the right box becoming taller than the left box?

Comment: @yunzen In my situation, no.

Comment: @DKyleo Added, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Would adding a div with nothing in it (but actual dimensions) on top of the div that wants to be centered on the blue line be the way to do this?

Comment: @Edunikki The problem is that I don't know the dimensions. I my snippet I added dimensions but that's just for an example. In my project the "boxes" are scaled to fit their content, so I use flexbox to do the vertical alignment. That's why doing something like `top: 25%` doesn't really work.

Comment: You won't be able to accomplish that with Flexbox alone. CSS Grid might, and adding a script.

Answer (score 6):

I only found a solution which uses JavaScript and grid.
In principle The JS should work with flex, too, but I started with grid, because I thought it wouldn't be possible with flex to begin with.

```js
{
  // define some vars local to this block
  // CSS selectors for the containers
  const containerSelector = '.container';
  const leftSelector = '.left-box';
  const rightSelector = '.right-box';

  // this function will recalculate the height of two grid boxes
  const recalc = () => {
    const containers = document.querySelectorAll(containerSelector);
    for (let container of containers) {
      const l = container.querySelector(`:scope > ${leftSelector} > *`).offsetHeight
      const r = container.querySelector(`:scope > ${rightSelector} > *`).offsetHeight
      const gap = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(container).gridRowGap)
      // +-----+  +-----+
      // |     |  |  c  |
      // |     |  +-----+  ------.
      // |     |                  }-- gap
      // |     |  +-----+  ------´
      // |  l  |  |  r  | 
      // |     |  +-----+  ------.
      // |     |                  }-- gap
      // |     |  +-----+  --.---´ 
      // |     |  |  c  |     }
      // +-----+  +- - -|     }------ text
      //          |     |     }
      //          +-----+  --´
      // l = c + gap + r + gap + c
      // l = 2 * c + 2 * gap + r
      // l - r - 2 * gap = 2 * c
      const c = (l - r - 2 * gap) / 2
      container.style.gridTemplateRows = `${c}px auto ${c}px auto`
    }
  }

  window.addEventListener('resize', recalc);
  window.addEventListener('load', recalc);
  recalc();
}
```

```css
.container {
  align-content: left;
  border: 1px solid gold;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto 1fr auto;
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 1rem 50px;
  padding: 25px;
  grid-template-areas: "leftbox b" "leftbox rightbox" "leftbox mytextbox" "a mytextbox";
}

.container .left-box {
  grid-area: leftbox;
  background-color: green;
}

.container .right-box {
  grid-area: rightbox;
  background-color: orange;
}

.container .text-box {
  grid-area: mytextbox;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.container figure {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 0;
}

.container figure img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-box">
    <figure>
      <img src="http://picsum.photos/225/300?image=990" alt="">
      <figcaption>Figure 1</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="right-box">
    <figure>
      <img src="http://picsum.photos/225/100?image=991" alt="">
      <figcaption>Figure 2</figcaption>

    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="text-box">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Est, cum porro quod unde neque doloribus excepturi odio nobis necessitatibus, nostrum labore id. Dolorem facere, quia nihil similique quis consectetur earum repudiandae non ut aperiam, dolore
    cum, corporis ratione quaerat temporibus.<br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corrupti quam impedit perspiciatis sit nulla officiis in, delectus adipisci aliquam dolores, ratione voluptates dolorem odio ab ducimus praesentium
    omnis! Unde, at?<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Without the JS part, the left-box would be too big, because the `1fr` unit is too greedy (or the `auto` rows are too relutant).

```css
.container {
  align-content: left;
  border: 1px solid gold;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto 1fr auto;
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 1rem 50px;
  padding: 25px;
  grid-template-areas: "leftbox b" "leftbox rightbox" "leftbox mytextbox" "a mytextbox";
}
.container .left-box {
  grid-area: leftbox;
  background-color: green;
}
.container .right-box {
  grid-area: rightbox;
  background-color: orange;
}
.container .text-box {
  grid-area: mytextbox;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.container figure {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 0;
}
.container figure img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-box">
    <figure>
      <img src="http://picsum.photos/225/300?image=990" alt="">
      <figcaption>Figure 1</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="right-box">
    <figure>
      <img src="http://picsum.photos/225/100?image=991" alt="">
      <figcaption>Figure 2</figcaption>

    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="text-box">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Est, cum porro quod unde neque doloribus excepturi odio nobis necessitatibus, nostrum labore id. Dolorem facere, quia nihil similique quis consectetur earum repudiandae non ut aperiam, dolore cum, corporis ratione quaerat temporibus.<br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corrupti quam impedit perspiciatis sit nulla officiis in, delectus adipisci aliquam dolores, ratione voluptates dolorem odio ab ducimus praesentium omnis! Unde, at?<br>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Est, cum porro quod unde neque doloribus excepturi odio nobis necessitatibus, nostrum labore id. Dolorem facere, quia nihil similique quis consectetur earum repudiandae non ut aperiam, dolore cum, corporis ratione quaerat temporibus.<br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corrupti quam impedit perspiciatis sit nulla officiis in, delectus adipisci aliquam dolores, ratione voluptates dolorem odio ab ducimus praesentium omnis! Unde, at?<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've created a `flex` version as well

```js
console.clear()
{
  const containerSelector = '.container';
  const leftColSelector = '.left-col';
  const rightColSelector = '.right-col';
  const leftSelector = '.left-box';
  const rightSelector = '.right-box';
  const rightSpacerSelector = '.right-spacer';

  const recalc = () => {
    const containers = document.querySelectorAll(containerSelector);
    for (let container of containers) {
      const l = container.querySelector(`:scope > ${leftColSelector} > ${leftSelector} > *`).offsetHeight;
      const r = container.querySelector(`:scope > ${rightColSelector} > ${rightSelector} > *`).offsetHeight;
      const s = container.querySelector(`:scope > ${rightColSelector} > ${rightSpacerSelector}`)
      const c = (l - r) / 2
      s.style.height = `${c}px`;
      // container.style.gridTemplateRows = `${c}px auto ${c}px auto`
    }
  }

  window.addEventListener('resize', recalc);
  window.addEventListener('load', recalc);
  recalc();
}
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid gold;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: flex;
  padding: 25px;
}
.container .left-col,
.container .right-col {
  width: calc(50% - 25px);
}
.container .left-col {
  margin-right: 25px;
}
.container .right-col {
  margin-left: 25px;
}
.container .left-box {
  background-color: green;
}
.container .right-box {
  background-color: orange;
}
.container .text-box {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.container figure {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 0;
}
.container figure img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-col">
    <div class="left-box">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://picsum.photos/225/300?image=990" alt="">
        <figcaption>Figure 1</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-col">
    <div class="right-spacer"></div>
    <div class="right-box">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://picsum.photos/225/100?image=991" alt="">
        <figcaption>Figure 2</figcaption>

      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="text-box">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Est, cum porro quod unde neque doloribus excepturi odio nobis necessitatibus, nostrum labore id. Dolorem facere, quia nihil similique quis consectetur earum repudiandae non ut aperiam, dolore
      cum, corporis ratione quaerat temporibus.<br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corrupti quam impedit perspiciatis sit nulla officiis in, delectus adipisci aliquam dolores, ratione voluptates dolorem odio ab ducimus praesentium
      omnis! Unde, at?<br>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

I hope this is solution you are looking for

```js
$(window).on('resize load', function(){
  var coll = $('.big-box').height();
  var sheight = $('.small-box').height();
  var calci = (coll - sheight)/2;
  $('.small-box').css({'margin-top':calci});
});
```

```css
.container {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 4px solid #00aaff;
  position:relative;
  height:auto;
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
}
.big-box{
  display:inline-block;
  width:49%;
  border:2px solid #000;
  float:left;
  height:200px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.right-div{
  display:inline-block;
  width:calc(100% - 49% - 20px);
  float:left;
  margin-left:20px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.small-box{
  border:2px solid #000;
  height:50px;
 
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
      <div class="big-box">
        Lots of content...
      </div>
      <div class="right-div">
        <div class="small-box">
            Some content...
        </div>
        <div class="group1">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is centering on the box and text combined, not just the box. The smaller of the two black boxes should be perfectly centered with the larger box. I added another picture to my post to help clarify.

Comment: Make the _"big box"_ 200px height and you'll see it won't work. The text will be pushed down by the left box instead of the right, which is not what is asked.

Comment: Ohh thank you for pointing that out @LGson. I assumed height going to be fixed for "big-box". However, I have updated my answer accordingly.